# pandas not retaining format of string when being modified

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have written a code for this type of string based data.

```
  501NA      NA    1   3.283   0.011   4.761
  502NA      NA    2   4.337   1.367   0.160
  503NA      NA    3   4.795   2.498   4.104
```

I convert it from txt to csv, which is then readable by pandas when modified by this program:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('processedblock2.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['index', 'x','y','z'])


 the data to a dataframe
refined = df[df.x >= df.y]
refined.style.hide_index()
refined.to_csv('pdboutput2.csv')
```

but the format of the document is lost. So with pandas or another way how can you retain the format of the original document and perform the operation of selecting data?

Comment: What do you mean by "format of the document? Do you want the output in that fixed-size fields format instead of CSV?

Comment: yes I want it to either go to that fixed-sized format with pandas, or if that isn't possible how can it be circumvented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, somehow, ensure that your data can be separated with
spaces you can read directly from the `.txt` file
using `sep="\s+"` (one or more tab/spaces as separator).
I have also added `keep_default_na=False` so the column with
NA values don't get replaced with `NaN` (and perhaps eliminated on the write to csv).

For the output to keep the format of the original document you can use the
`sep=" "` (different from the default `,`), and constrain the numbers to be
represented as float with only 3 decimals `float_format='%.3f'` (as the original document).

```
      id  NA  index      x      y      z  refined
0  501NA  NA      1  3.283  0.011  4.761     True
1  502NA  NA      2  4.337  1.367  0.160     True
2  503NA  NA      3  4.795  2.498  4.104     True
```

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep="\s+", header=None, keep_default_na=False)
print(data)
data.columns = ['id', 'NA', 'index', 'x', 'y', 'z']

data = data.assign(refined=lambda k:k.x >= k.y)
print(data)

data.to_csv('pdboutput2.csv', sep=" ", float_format='%.3f', index=False, header=False)
```

Output from **pdboutput2.csv**

```
501NA NA 1 3.283 0.011 4.761 True
502NA NA 2 4.337 1.367 0.160 True
503NA NA 3 4.795 2.498 4.104 True
```